# Extracting CSV Converters Into Methods

Tags: ruby, csv

I am creating a CSV Ruby object and have a few different custom converters that I am running. I was wondering how I can extract what I am doing in these converters into methods instead of lambdas.

Here is what I have:

```
CSV::Converters[:remove_dollar_sign] = lambda {|s| s.gsub(/(\$|\,)/, "") if s.is_a?(String)}
    CSV::Converters[:remove_quotes] = lambda {|s| s.gsub("\"","") if s.is_a?(String)}
    CSV::Converters[:strip_spaces] = lambda {|s| s.strip if s.is_a?(String)}
    CSV::Converters[:remove_hyphens] = lambda {|s| s.gsub(/\A\W/,"0") if s.is_a?(String)}
    CSV.parse(
      data, 
      headers: true, 
      header_converters: [:strip_headers], 
      converters: [:remove_dollar_sign, :remove_quotes, :strip_spaces, :remove_hyphens]
    )
```

I would like to create a method for each of those converters and instead just call the methods for each converter. For instance CSV::Converters[:remove_dollar_sign] would become a method called 'remove_dollar_sign' and I would just make that converter equal to the method. Make sense? This would make it easier to test each converter by itself.

I understand how lambdas work (at least I think I do) but I'm not sure what I would pass into a method if I used it in a converter in this case.

Answer (score 0):

`Method#call` works in a similar way as `Proc#call`.

```
def remove_dollar_sign s; s.gsub(/(\$|\,)/, "") if s.is_a?(String) end
def remove_quotes s; s.gsub("\"","") if s.is_a?(String) end
def strip_spaces s; s.strip if s.is_a?(String) end
def remove_hyphens s; s.gsub(/\A\W/,"0") if s.is_a?(String) end

CSV::Converters.merge!(
  remove_dollar_sign: method(:remove_dollar_sign),
  remove_quotes: method(:remove_quotes),
  strip_spaces: method(:strip_spaces),
  remove_hyphens: method(:remove_hyphens),
)
```

By the way, using `gsub` in `remove_hyphens` does not make sense, although it works.